# Calling a function from macro on a different document with MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel

Im calling a macro from another macro and it is working well im using

```
Application.Run("'name of the file'!function to call")
```

But the problem is that the function i need to call have a MsgBox and it expect the user to give the OK.

How can i send the OK by default? i cant change the original code.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: I would say no chance if you cannot change the original code. A workaround could be waiting for the MsgBox (a defined amount of time) and use [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx) to send a Enter. But this is no proper solution and could fail in many cases.

Comment: If you can't change the function code or there is no argument to set an OK, I guess this is not possible.

Comment: You will have to modify or add to the code, you aren't going to be able to wave a wand at this one.

Comment: OK, thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible... but you *probably* don't want to go there.

[Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (a VBE add-in OSS project I manage) uses [EasyHook](http://easyhook.github.io/index.html) to hook into `vbe7.dll` and intercept calls to `rtcMsgBox`, the internal function that gets called when VBA code invokes the `MsgBox` function.

This allows Rubberduck unit tests to setup a return value for the `MsgBox` function, without ever displaying an actual message box:

```
Fakes.MsgBox.Returns vbOk
DoSomething ' procedure under test, invokes a MsgBox that needs to say "Ok"
```

The hook is only enabled while a Rubberduck unit test is running though, so you couldn't use this API for what you need - but Rubberduck is open-source, and you could fork it and tweak it (it's written in C#) so that its `Fakes` API can be used in production code via a modified API that lets the client VBA code toggle the hook on and off.

Or you could write some fiendish Win32 API code and implement something similar.

Good luck!